# How to set width of <span> tag in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <span class="label">Product Name</span>
   <span>
      <mat-form-field>
         <input matInput formControlName="productName">
      </mat-form-field>
   </span>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.label { width: 180px; } span{ display: inline-block; }
```

In this code, class 'label' has fixed width but another span is not taking remaining width of col-md-8.

Comment: Can you show your CSS as well? Because by default `<span>` is `display: inline` and won't be affected by specified width.

Comment: Css code:                                                                                                       
     .label {
        width: 180px;
      }

      span{
        display: inline-block;
      }

Answer (score 1):

This is a CSS question, there needs be no angular.

With flexbox you can achieve the layout you desire.

Now what you probably should be doing is something like this:

```
<style>
  .labeled-input {
    display: flex;
  }
  .labeled-input input {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
</style>
<div class="labeled-input">
   <label for="productName">Product Name</label>
   <input name="productName" />
</div>
```

So use a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element for the label and set what input it's for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use column grid also on span tag and span in row class

here's an example

```
<div class="row">

    <span class="col-md-2">Product Name</span>
    <span class="col">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput>
        </mat-form-field>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
.label { width: 180px; } span{ width:100%; }
```